# Routing with Angular and Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I am learning Node and Angular. As part of my learning, I'm currently attempting to setup a basic app that has three pages. In an effort to do this, I've relied on the documentation available at: [enter link description here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.directive%3angView#animations).

My project is currently structured as follows though:

```
/app
  /views
    page1.html
    page2.html
    page3.html
  /resources
    /javascript
      angular-1.0.7.min.js
      controllers.js
  index.html
```

My code in index.html is straightforward. It looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ngView">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/javascript/angular-1.0.7.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/javascript/controllers.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="Index">
        <a href="page1">Page 1</a>
        <a href="page2">Page 2</a>
        <a href="page3">Page 3</a>

        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>        

    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('ngView', [], function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
                when('/page1', { templateUrl: 'app/views/page1.html', controller: Page1Controller }).
                when('/page2', { templateUrl: 'app/views/page2.html', controller: Page2Controller }).
                when('/page3', { templateUrl: 'app/views/page3.html', controller: Page3Controller }).
                otherwise({ redirectTo: 'app/views/page1' });

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

For some reason, my views are not appearing like they do in the example. What did I setup incorrectly?

Comment: I believe you have to setup your routes inside your node server file to let angular handle them (I've only done it with Express + Node)

Comment: Probably going to need to see the contents of that controller.js file

Comment: Yes - as @BoxerBucks said, we need to see the contents of the controller and also how you have set up your nodeJs server... Have you handled delivering or rendering of the templates?

Comment: Are the view files loading? Angular has a problem with subfolders in some situations - although this is usually related to the route paths and not the paths to the views...

Answer (score 0):

Are you forwarding the proper requests from your node server to angular? If using express this may look something like this:

```
router.all('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});
```